# How can I remove the FancyBox prev/play/next arrows in the navbar at the top of the FancyBox viewport?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, viewport, navbar, fancybox-2

I have thumbnails. If you click on these thumbnails, fancybox kicks in to show the bigger image. At the top of the viewport is a navbar with arrows that let you click to move left or right in the gallery, or to play the video if the thumbnail was a video. I don't want to have these buttons in that navbar. All I want is the resize button and the exit button.

I tried this in my js file:

```
$(".fancybox:not(.video)").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            buttons: {
                arrows: false,
            }
        }
    });
```

I also tried this as per other answers:

```
$(".fancybox:not(.video)").fancybox({
        arrows : false,
        helpers: {
            buttons: {}
        }
    });
```

I also tried:

```
    $(".fancybox:not(.video)").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            buttons: {},
            arrows : false
        }
    });
```

It doesn't work and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the button's `tpl` option to add/remove the buttons you want. This is the default template :

```
tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul>' +
    '<li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="btnNext" title="Next" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
    '</ul></div>'
```

From here you can remove the buttons you don't want in your custom script like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        helpers: {
            buttons: {
                tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul>' +
                    '<li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
                    '<li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:;"></a></li>' +
                    '</ul></div>'
            }
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

Also, you may need to adjust the `width` of the fancybox buttons area since you are removing some of them. You could add this CSS rule :

```
#fancybox-buttons ul {
    /* 166 for 4 buttons */
    width: 86px !important;
}
```

... that will fit for the 2 buttons left (tweak at your convenience)

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

**NOTE** : The `play` button is not to *play videos* but to start/pause a fancybox gallery of elements (if any)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, that was very helpful. Especially the part about tweaking the width. Really appreciate your time and your detailed answer. May I also ask how you learned this much about fancybox? I've been looking at their documentation but so far it seems rather sparse. (Or perhaps I just feel that it's sparse since I'm a newbie)

Comment: @HandleThatError : the best way to learn about fancybox (and/or any other plugin as matter of fact) is to analyze the source code of their JS (uncompressed) files. It's true there is not too much documentation but in this case for instance, if you open the buttons helper js file, you will see the `tpl` option as per this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this. Another question, if I may. If I analyze a plugin's uncompressed JS and become really good at JS, is it better to implement this kind of functionality on my own? Or does the professional world use plugins and frameworks freely, only checking the JS to understand better ways to use those plugins and frameworks?

When is it better to write my own JS and to understand JS on a deep level than to use something like fancybox or bootstrap or etc?

Comment: @HandleThatError : Personally I prefer coding things by myself rather than using plugins, however sometimes it doesn't worth re-inventing the wheel and using an existing (good, stable and well documented) plugin makes more sense. For sure, writing your own plugin is a good way to learn and expand your skills but also contributing to an existing plugin (finding bugs, documenting, translating or improving processes) is another way. Most plugins are open-source projects so you can always add value to them

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it and I'll make sure to take this to heart. :)